# Selenium returning me empty list with .find method,even though there are items

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

[HTML code][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrH0a.png**strong text**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

Path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(Path)

driver.get("https://www.emag.ro/")

search_bar = driver.find_element_by_id("searchboxTrigger")
search_bar.send_keys("laptopuri")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

main = None

try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main-container"))
    )
    print("Page loaded,main retrived succesfully")

    items = main.find_element_by_id("card_grid")
    products = items.find_elements_by_class_name("card-item js-product-data")
    print(products)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

If i use the find_elements method it returns me an empty list,but if i use the find_element method,for one element only,i get a no such element traceback.As you see,i am waiting for main to load,and selenium still can't find that class,but as you see in the picture it exists.I tried finding it directly without using the "items" variable.

This is my first post,i hope it is clear enough and alligned with the rules of the community

UPDATE:

items.find_elements_by_xpath works
I would appreciate an explanation as to why only this works

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_element_by_class_name()` receives only one class as parameter.
Instead what you may want to do is search by css selector

Thus:

```
products = items.find_elements_by_css_selector(".card-item.js-product-data")
```

Comment: I have tried that but as I said,with find element I get an error saying there is no such class when there clearly is and with find elementS,I get an empty list

Comment: Strange. Can you try to use `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".card-item.js-product-data")`, using the whole driver instead of the grid element?

Comment: Those classes are in main,because I am inputting text in the search bar,they aren't on the first page that the driver represents

Comment: Assuming that when your script executes the send_keys method on the driver, the driver doesn't open a new window or tab, it shall follow the page you're currently navigating. You can verify it by checking the url the driver is using by printing the `driver.current_url` attribute pre and post your send_keys function.

Comment: O so the driver follows the pages,didn't know,thanks a lot

Comment: Yep, also in your specific case it might be more useful to do something like:
`driver.get("https://www.emag.ro/search/" +  "laptopuri")` instead of relying of sendkeys to directly get to the page of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like some kind of a bug because  XPath works fine:

```
products_xpath = items.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/*[@class="card-item js-product-data"]')
```

Comment: You tested it on your pc?and find by class and css doesn't work and this works?

Comment: Yes, `By.CLASS_NAME` doesn't work for me too.

Comment: And find_elements_by_xpath and what you did are the same things just written differently?

Comment: Yes. It returns 60 results

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is bug in class name or css. Please try below :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, options = options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get("https://www.emag.ro/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//i[contains(@class,'close')]/parent::button[@class='close']"))).click()
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class,'js-accept')]")))).click().perform()

search_bar  = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "searchboxTrigger")))
search_bar.send_keys("laptopuri")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main-container")))
    print("Page loaded,main retrived succesfully")
    items = main.find_element_by_id("card_grid")
    products = items.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.card-item.js-product-data")
    for product in products:
        print(product.get_attribute('innerText'))
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

**Output :**

```
"C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" C:/Users/panabh02/PycharmProjects/SeleniumSO/Chrome.py
Page loaded,main retrived succesfully
-7%
Laptop HP 15-db1100ny cu procesor AMD Ryzen 5 3500U pana la 3.70 GHz, 15.6", Full HD, 4GB, 1TB HDD, AMD Radeon Vega 8, Free DOS, Black
(72)
ultimul produs in stoc
Rate online in 10 minute

2.38000 Lei

2.19900 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-40%
Laptop HP 15s-eq1053nq cu procesor Ryzen 3 3250U, 15.6", HD, 8GB, 256GB SSD, AMD Radeon Graphics, Windows 10 Home, Natural Silver
(2)
50% reducere M365Personal
4 rate fără dobândă

2.49999 Lei

1.49900 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-32%
Laptop Allview Allbook H cu procesor Intel Celeron N4000 pana la 2.60 GHz, 15.6", Full HD, 4GB, 256GB SSD, Intel UHD 600, Ubuntu, Grey
(60)
în stoc
4 rate fără dobândă

1.89999 Lei

1.28999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-29%
Laptop Lenovo ThinkBook 15 IIL cu procesor Intel Core i7-1065G7 pana la 3.90 GHz, 15.6", Full HD, 16GB, 512GB SSD, Intel Iris Plus Graphics, Free DOS, Mineral Grey
(24)
în stoc
eCREDIT Promo

4.49999 Lei

3.17999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-26%
Laptop ASUS X509MA cu procesor Intel Pentium Silver N5030, 15.6", HD, 4GB, 256GB SSD, Intel UHD Graphics 605, No OS, Slate Grey
(15)
în stoc
4 rate fără dobândă

1.89999 Lei

1.39999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-16%
Laptop ASUS X515MA cu procesor Intel® Celeron® N4020, 15.6", HD, 4GB, 256GB SSD, Intel® UHD Graphics 600, No OS, Transparent Silver
(1)
ultimele 2 produse
4 rate fără dobândă

1.78500 Lei

1.49000 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-41%
OUTLET
Laptop HP ProBook 450 G7 cu procesor Intel Core i3-10110U pana la 4.10 GHz, 15.6", Full HD, 32GB, 512GB SSD, Intel UHD Graphics, Free DOS, Pike Silver
(6)
în stoc
Rate online in 10 minute

4.29999 Lei

2.49999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
Laptop HP 15s-fq1060nq cu procesor Intel Core i3-1005G1, 15.6", HD, 4GB, 256GB SSD, Intel UHD Graphics, Free DOS, Natural silver
(2)
ultimul produs in stoc
4 rate fără dobândă

1.78500 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-35%
Laptop ultraportabil Prestigio SmartBook 133 C4 cu procesor AMD A4-9120e pana la 2.20 GHz, 14.1", HD, 4GB, 64GB eMMC, AMD Radeon R3, Windows 10 Pro, Dark Grey
(9)
50% reducere M365Personal
4 rate fără dobândă

1.99999 Lei

1.29999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-16%
Laptop Apple MacBook Air 13-inch, True Tone, procesor Apple M1 , 8 nuclee CPU si 7 nuclee GPU, 8GB, 256GB, Space Grey, INT KB
(76)
în stoc
eCREDIT Promo

5.59999 Lei

4.69999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-30%
Laptop Huawei MateBook D15 2021 cu procesor Intel® Core i3-10110U, 15.6", Full HD, 8GB, 256GB SSD, Intel® UHD Graphics 620, Windows 10 Home, Silver
(8)
50% reducere M365Personal
Rate online in 10 minute

3.29999 Lei

2.29999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-22%
Laptop Gaming ASUS TUF F15 FX506LH cu procesor Intel® Core™ i5-10300H pana la 4.50 GHz, 15.6", Full HD, 144Hz, 8GB, 512GB SSD, NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1650 4GB, Free DOS, Fortress Gray
(3)
în stoc
eCREDIT Promo

4.39999 Lei

3.39999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-23%
Laptop ultraportabil HP 14s-dq0000sf cu procesor Intel Celeron N4000 pana la 2.60 GHz Gemini Lake, 14", HD, 64GB eMMC, 4GB RAM, Intel UHD Graphics 600, Windows 10 Home S, Layout FR, Natural Silver
(1)
în stoc
4 rate fără dobândă

1.49900 Lei

1.14900 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-17%
Laptop Gaming ASUS TUF FX505DT cu procesorAMD Ryzen™ 7 3750H pana la 4.00 GHz, 15.6", Full HD, 144Hz, 16GB, 512GB SSD, NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1650 4GB, Free DOS, Stealth Black
(30)
în stoc
eCREDIT Promo

4.09999 Lei

3.39999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-28%
Laptop ASUS X515EA cu procesor Intel® Core™ i3-1115G4 pana la 4.10 GHz, 15.6", HD, 8GB, 256GB SSD, Intel® UHD Graphics, Free DOS, Slate Grey
(5)
în stoc
4 rate fără dobândă

2.49999 Lei

1.79999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-46%
Laptop ultraportabil HP 245 G7 cu procesor AMD Ryzen 3 3300U pana la 3.50 GHz, 14", HD, 4GB, 1TB HDD, AMD Radeon™ Vega 6 Graphics, Windows 10 Home, Black
(7)
10% COD EXTRA-REDUCERE
4 rate fără dobândă

3.19999 Lei

1.69999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-21%
Laptop Gaming Acer Nitro 5 AN515-55-5317 cu procesor Intel® Core™ i5-10300H pana la 4.50 GHz, 15.6", IPS, 144Hz, 8GB, 512GB SSD, NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1650Ti 4GB, No OS, Black
(4)
în stoc
eCREDIT Promo

5.09999 Lei

3.99999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-33%
Laptop Lenovo IdeaPad 3 15IML05 cu procesor Intel Celeron 5205U pana la 1.90 GHz, 15.6", HD, 4GB, 128GB SSD, Intel UHD Graphics, Free DOS, Platinum Grey
(1)
în stoc
4 rate fără dobândă

1.79999 Lei

1.19999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-11%
Laptop Gaming ASUS ROG Strix G15 cu procesor AMD Ryzen™ 9 5900HX, 15.6", Full HD, 300Hz, 16GB, 1TB SSD, NVIDIA® GeForce RTX™ 3060 6GB, No OS, Eclipse Gray
(4)
disponibil in showroom
eCREDIT Promo

7.69999 Lei

6.79999 Lei

Rezerva in Showroom
-50%
Laptop ultraportabil Weigo cu procesor Intel Core i3-5005U 2.00 GHz, 14.1" Full HD, 8GB, 256GB SSD, Intel HD Graphics 5500, Windows 10 Pro, Grey
(9)
50% reducere M365Personal
4 rate fără dobândă

2.99999 Lei

1.49999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
Laptop ASUS M509DA cu procesor AMD Ryzen™ 3 3250U pana la 3.50 GHz, 15.6", Full HD, 8GB, 256GB SSD, AMD Radeon™ Graphics, Free DOS, Slate Grey
(9)
disponibil in showroom
Rate online in 10 minute

2.64999 Lei

Vezi Detalii
-34%
Laptop ultraportabil Acer Swift 1 SF114-33 cu procesor Intel® Celeron® N4120 pana la 2.60 GHz, 14”, Full HD, 4GB, 128GB SSD, Inel UHD Graphics, No OS, SIlver
(23)
în stoc
4 rate fără dobândă

2.29999 Lei

1.49999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-15%
Laptop ASUS X509MA cu procesor Intel Pentium Silver N5030, 15.6", HD, 4GB, 1TB HDD, Intel UHD Graphics 605, No OS, No OS, Transparent silver
(1)
în stoc
4 rate fără dobândă

1.89999 Lei

1.59999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-36%
Laptop Allview Allbook J cu procesor Intel® Celeron™ J4125 pana la 2.70 GHz, 15.6", Full HD, 8GB, 256GB SSD, Intel® UHD Graphics 600, Free DOS, Grey
(5)
în stoc
4 rate fără dobândă

2.49999 Lei

1.59999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-17%
Laptop Gaming ASUS ROG Strix G15 G513IH cu procesor AMD Ryzen™ 7 4800H, 15.6", Full HD, 144Hz, 16GB, 1TB SSD, NVIDIA® GeForce GTX™ 1650 4GB, No OS, Eclipse Gray
în stoc
eCREDIT Promo

5.09999 Lei

4.19999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-15%
Laptop Gaming Lenovo IdeaPad 3 15ARH05 cu procesor AMD Ryzen 7 4800H pana la 4.20 GHz, 15.6", Full HD, IPS, 8GB, 256GB SSD, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 4GB, Free DOS, Black
(10)
disponibil in showroom
eCREDIT Promo

3.89999 Lei

3.29999 Lei

Rezerva in Showroom
-16%
Laptop Apple MacBook Air 13-inch, True Tone, procesor Apple M1 , 8 nuclee CPU si 7 nuclee GPU, 8GB, 256GB, Gold, INT KB
(18)
în stoc
eCREDIT Promo

5.59999 Lei

4.69999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-33%
Laptop Gaming MSI GF63 Thin 10SC-070XRO cu procesor Intel® Core™ i5-10300H, 15.6", Full HD, 8GB, 256GB SSD, NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1650 Max-Q 4GB, Free DOS, Black
ultimele 2 produse

4.49999 Lei

2.99999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-32%
Laptop ASUS X515MA cu procesor Intel® Celeron® N4020 pana la 2.80 GHz, 15.6", HD, 4GB, 256GB SSD, Intel® UHD Graphics 600, Free DOS, Slate Grey
(27)
în stoc
4 rate fără dobândă

1.89900 Lei

1.28500 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-16%
Laptop ASUS VivoBook M712DA cu procesorAMD Ryzen™ 5 3500U, 17.3", HD+, 8GB, 512GB SSD, Radeon™ Vega 8 Graphics, No OS, Transparent Silver
(1)
disponibil in showroom
Rate online in 10 minute

2.74999 Lei

2.29999 Lei

Rezerva in Showroom
-17%
Laptop ASUS X515EA cu procesor Intel® Core™ i3-1115G4, 15.6", Full HD, 8GB, 256GB SSD, Intel® UHD Graphics, Windows 10 Home S, Transparent Silver
(2)
50% reducere M365Personal
Rate online in 10 minute

2.89999 Lei

2.39999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-29%
Laptop Lenovo ThinkBook 15 G2 ITL cu procesor Intel Core i3-1115G4 pana la 4.10 GHz, 15.6", Full HD, 8GB, 256GB SSD, Intel UHD Graphics, Free DOS, Mineral Grey
(17)
în stoc
Rate online in 10 minute

3.09999 Lei

2.19999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-34%
Laptop ultraportabil Jumper EzBook X3 cu procesor Intel Celeron N3450 Quad - Core pana la 2.20 GHz, 13.3", Full HD, 8GB, 128GB SSD, Intel® HD Graphics 500, Windows 10 Home, Grey
(1)
50% reducere M365Personal
4 rate fără dobândă

2.19999 Lei

1.44999 Lei

Rezerva in Showroom
-18%
Laptop Gaming ASUS TUF F15 FX506LH cu procesor Intel® Core™ i5-10300H, 15.6", Full HD, 144Hz, 8GB, 1TB SSD, NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1650 4GB, No OS, Fortress Gray
(1)
în stoc
eCREDIT Promo

4.39999 Lei

3.59999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-2%
Laptop HP 15s-fq2017nq cu procesor Intel® Core™ i5-1135G7 pana la 4.20 GHz, 15.6", Full HD, 8GB, 256GB SSD, Intel Iris Xe Graphics, Free DOS, Indigo Blue
(5)
în stoc
eCREDIT Promo

3.03312 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-34%
Laptop Gaming HP Pavilion 15-dk1027nq cu procesor Intel® Core™ i7-10750H pana la 5.00 GHz, 15.6", Full HD, 8GB, 512GB SSD, NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1660 Ti Max-Q 6GB, Free DOS, Black
(4)
10% COD EXTRA-REDUCERE
eCREDIT Promo

6.89999 Lei

4.49999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-33%
Laptop Acer Aspire 5 A515-44 cu procesor AMD Ryzen 7 4700U pana la 4.10 GHz, 15.6", Full HD, 16GB, 512GB SSD, AMD Radeon™ Graphics, No Os, Black
(10)
în stoc

4.49999 Lei

2.99999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-21%
Laptop ASUS X515JA cu procesor Intel® Core™ i3-1005G1, 15.6", Full HD, 8GB, 256GB SSD, Intel® UHD Graphics, Windows 10 Home S, Transparent Silver
(1)
50% reducere M365Personal
Rate online in 10 minute

2.79999 Lei

2.19999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-22%
Laptop ultraportabil Lenovo IdeaPad 3 14IIL05 cu procesor Intel Core i5-1035G1 pana la 3.60 GHz, 14", Full HD, 8GB, 512GB SSD, Intel UHD Graphics, No OS, Platinum Grey
(3)
în stoc
Rate online in 10 minute

2.94999 Lei

2.29999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-38%
Laptop ultraportabil Dell Latitude 3410 cu procesor Intel® Celeron™ 5205U 1.90 GHz, 14", Full HD, 4GB, 128GB SSD, Intel UHD Graphics, Ubuntu, Grey
(22)
în stoc
4 rate fără dobândă

2.69999 Lei

1.64999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
Laptop ASUS E410MA cu procesor Intel Celeron N4020 pana la 2.80 GHz, 14", Full HD, 4GB, 256GB SSD, Intel® UHD Graphics 600, Free DOS, Peacock Blue
(17)
în stoc
4 rate fără dobândă

1.73399 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-41%
Laptop Lenovo IdeaPad 3 15IML05 cu procesor Intel® Celeron® 5205U, 15.6" HD, 4GB, 128GB SSD, Intel® UHD Graphics, Windows 10 Home S, Platinum Grey
(11)
50% reducere M365Personal
4 rate fără dobândă

2.39999 Lei

1.39999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-29%
Laptop ultraportabil ASUS ZenBook 13 OLED UX325EA cu procesor Intel® Core™ i5-1135G7, 13.3", Full HD, 8GB, 512GB SSD, Intel Iris Xᵉ Graphics, Free DOS, Lilac Mist
(3)
în stoc
eCREDIT Promo

4.69999 Lei

3.29999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
Laptop Gaming ROG Strix G17 Advantage Edition G713QY cu procesor AMD Ryzen™ 9 5900HX, 17.3", WQHD, 165Hz, 16GB, 1TB SSD, AMD® Radeon™ RX 6800M 12GB, No OS, Original Black
ultimul produs in stoc
eCREDIT Promo

9.24000 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-13%
Laptop Acer Aspire 3 cu procesor Intel® Pentium® Silver N5030 pana la 3.10 GHz, 15.6", Full HD, 8GB, 128GB SSD, Intel® UHD Graphics 600, No OS, Black
(5)
disponibil in showroom
4 rate fără dobândă

1.84999 Lei

1.59999 Lei

Rezerva in Showroom
-34%
Laptop Apple MacBook Air 13 cu procesor Intel® Dual Core™ i5 1.80GHz, 13.3", 8GB, 128GB SSD, Intel® HD Graphics 6000, INT KB, Silver
(127)
în stoc
eCREDIT Promo

5.79999 Lei

3.79999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-6%
Laptop Gaming Lenovo IdeaPad 3 15ARH05, AMD Ryzen™ 5 4600H, 8GB DDR4, SSD 256GB, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 4GB, Free DOS
(4)
în stoc

3.19999 Lei

2.99999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-21%
Laptop Gaming ASUS TUF A15 FA506IU cu procesor AMD Ryzen 7 4800H pana la 4.30 GHz, 15.6", Full HD, 144Hz, 8GB 1TB SSD, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660Ti 6GB, Free DOS, Bonfire Black
(12)
disponibil in showroom
eCREDIT Promo

5.59999 Lei

4.39999 Lei

Rezerva in Showroom
-20%
Laptop Acer Aspire 3 A315-35 cu procesor Intel® Celeron® N4500 pana la 2.80 GHz, 15.6", Full HD, 8GB, 256GB SSD, Intel® UHD Graphics, No OS, Silver
(15)
în stoc
4 rate fără dobândă

1.74999 Lei

1.39999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-17%
Laptop Gaming HP Pavilion 16-a0003nq cu procesor Intel® Core™ i5-10300H, 16.1", Full HD, 8GB, 512GB SSD, NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1650 Ti 4GB, Free DOS, Black
10% COD EXTRA-REDUCERE
eCREDIT Promo

4.59999 Lei

3.79999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-27%
Laptop Huawei MateBook D15 2021 cu procesor Intel® Core™ i5-10210U pana la 4.20 GHz pana la 4.20 GHz, 15.6", Full HD, IPS, 16GB, 512GB SSD, Intel® UHD Graphics, Windows 10 Home, Silver
(17)
50% reducere M365Personal
eCREDIT Promo

4.69999 Lei

3.39999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-22%
Laptop ultraportabil ASUS E410MA cu procesor Intel® Celeron® N4020 pana la 2.80 GHz, 14", Full HD, 4GB, 256GB SSD, Intel® UHD Graphics 600, Free DOS, Peacock Blue
(58)
în stoc
4 rate fără dobândă

1.79999 Lei

1.39999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-30%
Laptop 2 in 1 Lenovo IdeaPad Duet 3 10IGL5 cu procesor Intel Celeron N4020, 10.3", WUXGA, Touch, IPS, 4GB, 128GB SSD, Intel UHD Graphics 600, Windows 10 Home S, Graphite Grey
(2)
50% reducere M365Personal
4 rate fără dobândă

2.14999 Lei

1.49999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-15%
Laptop Gaming HP OMEN 15-ek0002nq cu procesor Intel® Core™ i7-10750H pana la 5.00 GHz, 15.6", Full HD, 144Hz, 8GB, 512GB SSD, NVIDIA® GeForce RTX™ 2060 6GB, Free DOS, Black
(2)
10% COD EXTRA-REDUCERE
eCREDIT Promo

7.59999 Lei

6.39999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-11%
Laptop ASUS M515 cu procesor AMD Ryzen™ 3 3250U pana la 3.50 GHz, 15.6", HD, 8GB, 256GB SSD, AMD Radeon™ Graphics, Free DOS, Slate Grey
(8)
ultimul produs in stoc
4 rate fără dobândă

2.09999 Lei

1.84999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-18%
Laptop Gaming ASUS TUF F15 FX506LH cu procesor Intel® Core™ i7-10870H pana la 5.00 GHz, 15.6", Full HD, 144Hz, 16GB, 512GB SSD, NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1650 4GB , Free DOS, Fortress Gray
(3)
în stoc
eCREDIT Promo

5.39999 Lei

4.39999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-20%
Laptop Lenovo IdeaPad 3 15IML05 cu procesor Intel® Pentium® Gold 6405U, 15.6" HD, 4GB, 128GB SSD, Intel® UHD Graphics, Windows 10 Home S, Platinum Grey
(2)
50% reducere M365Personal
4 rate fără dobândă

2.14999 Lei

1.69999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-12%
Laptop Apple MacBook Pro 13-inch,True Tone, procesor Apple M1, 8 nuclee CPU si 8 nuclee GPU, 8GB, 256GB SSD, Space Grey, INT KB
(39)
în stoc
eCREDIT Promo

7.09999 Lei

6.19999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-24%
Laptop ultraportabil Huawei MateBook 14 cu procesor AMD Ryzen 5 4600H pana la 4.00 GHz, 14", 2K, 16GB, 512GB SSD, AMD Radeon Graphics, Windows 10 Home, Gray
(27)
50% reducere M365Personal
eCREDIT Promo

4.99999 Lei

3.79999 Lei

Adauga in Cos
-25%
Laptop ultraportabil Chuwi GemiBook cu procesor Intel Celeron J4115, 13", 256GB SSD, 12GB RAM, Intel® UHD Graphics, Windows 10 Home, Space Gray
(2)
în stoc
4 rate fără dobândă

1.99900 Lei

1.49900 Lei

Adauga in Cos

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: So why doesn't it work the normal way,when doing items.find_elements_by_class_name,but items.find_elements_by_xpath works.I am a beginner so I would really appreciate an explanation

Comment: @DragosCiupe : Selenium does not have support for classes with spaces. if you see multiple classes separated with a space that means they are individual classes, and representing different entity in the web page, in order to to get rid off of that we have to use either css, like I have used or xpath. CSS performs much faster and consistent than xpath, that's the reason I have given solution in css.

Comment: I tried css the normal way and it still didn't work

Comment: @DragosCiupe :  I did this `products = items.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.card-item.js-product-data")` and it worked, otherwise how do you think I would have got the above output ?

Comment: Oh sorry I just got confused by all the code you added

Comment: You can remove spaces and put a dot in place of that, and simply that will become css selector instead of class. I hope that will be helpful info.